# How can I call reactjs function on google maps marker onClick event

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

> I have reactjs modal popup function,

```
getModal: function() {
return (
  <Modal>
    <ModalBody>
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
);
```

},

> so how can I call getModal function on google maps marker onClick event, here is a code. this.getModal() - not works... so how get this function.

```
 componentDidMount: function() {  
   function placeMarker(location) {
    var addMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      icon: "/imgs/marker.png"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'click', function(){
       this.getModal();
    });
  }
 }
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler have different context (`this`) in time of execution. You can bind it to correct context like:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'click', (function(){
    this.getModal();
}).bind(this));
```

or:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'click', this.getModal.bind(this));
```

Comment: As I can see you return react element from `getModal` function, but it is not how React works. You should set state in your event handler and render modal conditionaly in `render` method. learn more here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of your context, i.e., the meaning of 'this' when writing javascript. It changes all the time when using APIs and frameworks such as GMaps and jQuery.

In your case, you will need to reference the object that has getModal() in its context, so: `something.getModal();`